# Merging different objects using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class :

```
public class A {
     String type;
     List<String> names;
}
```

Given a list of objects of this class (`List<A>`) how can I create a `Map<String, A'>` in which :

- the key is the `type` `String`.
- the value `A'` is a **new** object of type `A`, formed by merging all `A` instances of the input list having the same `type` - the `names` `List` of that new object will contain all the names of the merged `A` instances' `names` lists.

I tried using `toMap` and `groupingBy` from Java Collectors framework, but `toMap` throws an `IllegalStateException` since there are duplicate keys, whereas `groupingBy` creates a map of the form `Map<String, List<A>>`, whereas I want a `Map<String, A>`.

Comment: what have you tried so for? Better to show that with an example of input and expected output.

Comment: That suggested duplicate is not closely related to this question.

Comment: @choasia The type of 'A' is the class mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Eran why that? The topic is partially the same. the part where two equal `type` for two different instances of `A` will be a merged into a single `A` with the content of both `names` `List`'s beeing merged is the one thing not beeing adressed there. Though i wouldn´t mark it as a dupe of it either, but it contains necessary information.

Comment: @KevinEsche The problem in this question cannot be solved with a simple `Collectors.toMap` (as the duplicate target, which is a much simpler question), since the OP is not mapping each element of the input List to a single entry of the output Map. This question requires `Collectors.groupingBy` and even that won't be enough, since the value of the output map should be an aggregation of the `A` instances grouped for the same key.

Comment: I'm voting to open since it's not a correct duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it can be done in a single Stream pipeline (though I think it may be possible in [Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071600)).

`groupingBy` takes you in the right direction, but you cannot combine it with another `Collector` that would map the `List<A>` elements into a single `A` instance (that contains all the names).

You can use two `Stream` pipelines :

```
Map<String, A> result =
    listOfA.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.type)) // Map<String,List<A>>
           .entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey (),
                             e -> new A (e.getKey(),
                                         e.getValue()
                                          .stream()
                                          .flatMap(a->a.names.stream()) 
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

This assumes that `A` has an `A (String type, List<String> names)` constructor.

The `names` `List` of the output `A` instances may include duplicates. If you don't want that, you can collect the names to a `Set` and then create a `List` initialized by that `Set`.

Comment: Or you create a custom `Collector` creating `A`s in the first place. [Then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41146162/2711488), it works with a single Stream op and under Java 8. As a rule of thumb, whenever the elements end up being stored in a Collection, you can get away without the [`flatMapping`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector by simply replacing `add` with `addAll` (compared to the ordinary `toList()` or `toCollection(…)` Collector).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `A`’s constructor initializes `names` with a mutable `List`, you can use

```
Map<String, A> result=list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.type, Collector.of(A::new,
        (a,t)  ->{ a.type=t.type; a.names.addAll(t.names); },
        (a1,a2)->{ a1.names.addAll(a2.names); return a1; })));
```

Otherwise, you had to use

```
Map<String, A> result=list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.type, Collector.of(
        ()     ->{ A a = new A(); a.names=new ArrayList<>(); return a; },
        (a,t)  ->{ a.type=t.type; a.names.addAll(t.names); },
        (a1,a2)->{ a1.names.addAll(a2.names); return a1; })));
```

Of course, the code would be simpler, if you have a real class with usable methods instead of that `A` sketch consisting of two fields only.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the value of the `Map` with a combined value with the `toMap` `Collector`.

If your class `A` looks like this:

```
class A {
  private final String type;
  private final List<String> names;

  private A(String type, List<String> names) {
    this.type = type;
    this.names = names;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public List<String> getNames() {
    return names;
  }

  public static A merge(A a, A b) {
    if (!Objects.equals(a.type, b.type)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return of(a.type, Stream.concat(a.names.stream(), b.names.stream()).toArray(String[]::new));
  }

  public static A of(String type, String... names) {
    return new A(type, Arrays.asList(names));
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "A [type=" + type + ", names=" + names + "]";
  }

}
```

You can easily create your desired output with:

```
List<A> list = Arrays.asList(A.of("a", "a", "b", "c"), A.of("a", "d", "e"), A.of("b"), A.of("c", "x", "y", "z"));

Map<String, A> collect = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getType, Function.identity(), A::merge));
```

Outcome:

```
{a=A [type=a, names=[a, b, c, d, e]], b=A [type=b, names=[]], c=A [type=c, names=[x, y, z]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you failed to use `toMap` is because you didn't provide a merge function to handle the duplicate keys. (See the javadoc for the three-argument version of [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), which includes an excellent example for merging addresses.)

Here is my solution, which is similar to the answer provided by [Flown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41144615/7098259), but makes no changes to the original class (my code does not assume it is an immutable type).

```
    Map<String, A> result = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                a -> a.type, // keyMapper
                a -> { // valueMapper
                    A value = new A();
                    value.type = a.type;
                    value.names = new ArrayList<>(a.names);
                    return value;
                },
                (A value1, A value2) -> { // mergeFunction
                    value1.names.addAll(value2.names);
                    return value1;
                }));
```